# Having a class and ID together in an HTMLHelper method. ie. Text

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, textbox, html-helper

I saw this implemented somewhere but basically below I'm using the textbox HTMLHelper to draw a textbox with the id myID and default text 'text_goes_here'. I want to also add a class to thiis helper, i saw somewhere it implemented with new {@class =''} as a third parameter creating an object but im not sure exactly how its wrote

```
 <%= Html.TextBox("myID", "text_goes_here") %>
```

anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= Html.TextBox("myID", "text_goes_here", new {@class = "className"}) %>
```